# Zimun over the phone

Tags: bentching, phone, zimun

If one had a group call (perhaps with video) and during that call many participants had bread, could they make a zimun together?

I know that you only need to be within earshot to answer for a zimun, but what if you were never together in the first place. And does the internet count as within earshot?

I'm guessing it could be ok, because you have had a meal with eachother, though not physically. If strangers had a meal together physically, they can't make a zimmun - seemingly the meal conversation matters more than their proximity.

Comment: Assuming, of course, that they specifically sat down together on the video chat to eat together, akin to the halachos regarding eating together in person?

Comment: "I know that you only need to be within earshot to answer for a zimun" I don't think this is accurate.

Comment: I would remind you that a zimun would have requirements similar to a minyan. Thus just as there cannot be a *virtual* minyan there cannot be a *virtual* zimun.